# PowerShell issue adding user information from AD into Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Anyone good with hash tables ale to help out on this one. I have multiple global groups where I am gather each member of the groups. I am trying to add them to a hash table, each line contains all the information about the user account being returned where the $group is the key.

When I use $vdiArr.add I get the error Cannot find an overload for "add" and the argument count: "9".
When I remove the hashed out command it works fine but the data in the array seems to be all over the place. I am trying to achieve each user's information on one line within the array. e.g vdiArr[0]={theirGroup,Name, GivenName, LastName and so on....

```
clear-host
$count = $null
$date = Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$vdiGrps = Get-Content "D:\SourceFiles$\Scripts\Active Directory\ADGroups.txt"

$vdiArr=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@{}
$vdiArr=@{}

    foreach($group in $vdiGrps)
    {
        $ADgroup=(get-adgroup $group -properties members).members | get-adobject | where {$_.objectclass -eq "User"}| get-aduser -properties * | select name, GivenName, Surname, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, Enabled, DistinguishedName
        $ADgroup

        $vdiArr.add($group,$ADgroup.name,$ADgroup.GivenName,$ADgroup.Surname,$ADgroup.UserPrincipalName,$ADgroup.SamAccountName,$ADgroup.SamAccountName,$ADgroup.Enabled,$ADgroup.DistinguishedName)

        #$vdiArr.group = $group
        #$vdiArr.Name = $ADgroup.name
        #$vdiArr.GivenName = $ADgroup.GivenName
        #$vdiArr.Surname = $ADgroup.Surname
        #$vdiArr.UserPrincipalName = $ADgroup.UserPrincipalName
        #$vdiArr.SamAccountName = $ADgroup.SamAccountName
        #$vdiArr.Enabled = $ADgroup.Enabled
        #$vdiArr.DistinguishedName = $ADgroup.DistinguishedName


    }


$arrOutput += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $vdiArr
Out-File -InputObject $arrOutput -FilePath "$home\Desktop\test.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$vdiGrps = Get-Content "D:\SourceFiles$\Scripts\Active Directory\ADGroups.txt"

# Create empty array list.
$vdiArr=[System.Collections.ArrayList] @()

foreach($group in $vdiGrps)
{

    # Get users in group.
    $ADgroup=(get-adgroup $group -properties members).members | get-adobject | where {$_.objectclass -eq "User"}| get-aduser -properties * | select name, GivenName, Surname, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, Enabled, DistinguishedName

    # Loop over all users in group and add them to the output array.
    foreach($user in $ADgroup) {
      $null = $vdiArr.Add([pscustomobject] @{
        Group = $group
        Name = $user.name
        GivenName = $user.GivenName
        Surname = $user.Surname
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
        Enabled = $user.Enabled
        DistinguishedName = $user.DistinguishedName
      })
    }

}

Out-File -InputObject $vdiArr -FilePath "$HOME\Desktop\test.csv"
```

- `$null = ...` suppresses the (undesired) output from the `.Add()` call.
- The above approach demonstrates how to construct a custom object from a hashtable, but note that if you added a `Group` property as a calculated property to your `Select-Object` call, you could add the resulting objects *directly* to the output array.

---

As for **what you've tried**:

`$vdiArr=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@{}` is probably not what you intended, because casting the empty *hashtable* literal - `@{}` - to `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` results in an empty array list - the same as `[System.Collections.ArrayList] @()` (casting from an empty *array* literal) or `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`

That said, your very next statement - `$vdiArr=@{}` - completely overrides your previous statement and assigns an empty hashtable to `$vdiArr`, making the type of `$vdiArr` `[hashtable]` (`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`).

Your `.Add()` call then fails, because a hashtable's `.Add()` method only accepts *2* arguments - the key and the name of the new entry - not the 9 you're giving it.

That said, even if `$vdiArr` were a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance, as you probably intended, the `.Add()` call wouldn't work, because `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`'s `.Add()` method only accepts a *single* argument - the new element to add.